# np.dot with type bool but int result?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix `m` that has shape `(1024, 4096)` and a vector `v` with shape `(4096,)`. But contain only 0s and 1s. When I multiply them using `np.dot(m, v)` I'm getting the scalar product but since I have to do that step with several matrixes quite often, that step is quite slow.

So, I casted both the matrixes and the vectors to type `bool`. Now, the calculation of the dot product is very fast, but the result is not an integer or float but a bool value as well, which may be technically correct but is not what I need.

One solution I found was `np.dot(m, v.astype(int))` but I assume `m` then gets casted to int as well and the speed gain is gone.

Comment: `np.dot(m, v).astype(np.int)`?

Comment: What are the datatypes of `m` and `v`?

Comment: `np.dot(m, v)` gives me `array([True, True, False, ...])`, when casting that to int I'm getting `array([1, 1, 0, ...])`

Comment: The datatypes are originally `np.int`, but I'm casting them to `np.bool` for speed purposes which then also affects the result, which is `bool` as well but needs to be `int` to give me the correct information.

Comment: I would say stick to `np.dot(m,v)`. With `bool` conversion, the result might not be correct (if you have more than one `1` in one col of `m`). Also, I don't understand, why you are doing `v.astype(int)`, when you said that originally they are of int dtypes.

Comment: I did `v.astype(int)` only to show to you what type which variable has. I'm currently trying `np.int16`.

Comment: The bool dot appears multiply terms with logical_and, and sum them with logical_or.  The result is the same as the integer `np.dot(m,v)>0`, true where the regular dot is non-zero.

Comment: In quick tests all the numeric (not boolean) `dots` time the same.  `dot` passes the job to compiled code; that code has been compiled for only a few of the possible `dtypes`.  `np.einsum` with integers is about 2x faster.